# Lookup if a date falls between two dates stored in a range

Tags: excel, vba

There are many similar sounding questions to this but they either seem to be about Excel formulas (instead of actual VBA code) or they just don't fit my problem.

I have a named range in my sheet which lists a few time periods along with their respective start and end dates:

[image: Periods range in Excel]

I've named the range from M6 to O19 as "Periods" (the named range excludes the headers).

I need to have a VBA function which will check for the first Period for which a given date is greater than "Start" and less than "End".

Again, I have trawled through dozens of questions on SO but honestly nothing helped me. I've tried to adapt multiple answers to my problem but I'm still now left with an empty sub:

```
Public Function LookupNTAPeriod(lookupDate As Date) As String



End Function
```

Comment: Since the table is sorted, you can use `VLOOKUP`, or `Application.Vlookup` if you want VBA.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Why do you want to return string instead of corresponding row?

Comment: And how/where do you like the code to return the appropriate match? To return the matched  "Period"?

Comment: `For Each Row In Range("Periods").Rows: If lookupDate >= Row.Cells(1,2).Value And lookupDate <= Row.Cells(1,3).Value Then ...` Its a simple loop with an If statement.

Answer (score 0):

Please, use the next function:

```
Public Function LookupNTAPeriod(lookupDate As Date) As String
    Dim arr, i As Long
    Const rngName = "myName" 'please, use here your named range real name
    arr = Range(rngName).Value 'place the range in an array for faster iteration/processing
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        If lookupDate >= CDate(arr(i, 2)) And lookupDate <= CDate(arr(i, 3)) Then
            LookupNTAPeriod = arr(i, 1): Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    LookupNTAPeriod = "No match found..."
End Function
```

It can be tested in the next way:

```
Sub testLookupNTAPeriod()
    Dim lkDate As Date
    lkDate = Date
   
    Debug.Print LookupNTAPeriod(lkDate)
End Sub
```

It returns the matching "Period" from the named range first column